# Populate fields or return object

Tags: object-oriented-design, api-design

**What is better to do in this type of scenario: populate fields or return an object?**

The situation is like this: I'm doing calculations to find the prices (inc tax, ex tax, discounted etc) of a product. Is there any advice or are there any guidelines on how to handle a return value?

Populate fields:

```
public class ProductPrice
{
    public int BasePrice;
    public int IncTax;
    public int ExTax;
    // ...

    public void GetPricesForProduct(int ProductID)
    { /* Populate fields based on results */ }
}
```

Return object:

```
public class PriceCalculator
{
    public ProductPrice GetPricesForProduct(int ProductID)
    { /* Populate object fields and return object */ }
}
public class ProductPrice
{
    public int BasePrice;
    public int IncTax;
    public int ExTax;
}
```

I'm not sure I really like the first method, because the `void` return type doesn't make it clear what happens when the method executes. However, returning an object results in a class which has no functionality.

Comment: In what language? Java/C#? Which is preferred will matter a bit on the idioms of the language you're using.

Comment: @Telastyn, based on the brackets and naming convention, I'd say C#, but it's hard to say.

Comment: In the first case, why do you need to pass productId to the method , If productPrice object itslef knows its own Id?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're right to prefer the second method.  The first method would easily clutter a class with members that would better be suited torwards an object which represents those values.

Better still, add a method to ProductPrice which performs the calculation and change "PriceCalculator" to "PriceFetcher" which simply gets the raw values and instantiates ProductPrice.

```
public class PriceFetcher
{
    public ProductPrice GetPricesForProduct(int ProductID)
    { /* Populate object fields and return object */ }
}
public class ProductPrice
{
    public int BasePrice;
    public int IncTax;
    public int ExTax;

    public float GetPrice() 
    { /* Perform calculation on given data */ }
}
```

This method has the added advantage that the object determines how the price is calculated and not the method which fetched the data, allowing you to do more complicated operations later with derived classes of ProductPrice and instantiate them using a factory in PriceFetcher.

Comment: I like the idea of the ProductPrice class implementing the calculation logic

Answer (score 2):

The second approach appears better to me. It decouples price from product.

The class may not have any behavior at this time, but it may in the future. Even if it doesn't it doesn't mean it doesn't have a function - holding data that doesn't belong to the product class.

Comment: +1.  Always favor a more simplistic and modularized approach or you risk having classes which perform multiple tasks.

Answer (score 2):

Well the use of `void` doesn't make sense as it conflicts with the name of the function.  If you have a something that is called `get***` I expect that to return an object (or a primitive).  The second approach seems to be more correct as your `PriceCalculator` is really the `main` program (at least that is how it looks in this trivial example).  I would rename the function to `GetPricesForProductById` as that is what you are doing, not getting prices by a `Product`

Answer (score 1):

the second option (the factory model) is better (add the id to the returned object and make it immutable for completion but that is all I would change)

when you have a method named `get*` one expects it to return something but even `calculatePricesForProduct` lacks what it should be because you start from an different object and overwrite it with the new product. This type of mutable objects are a pain to safely work with (making a copy of it everywhere you need to use it) unless you planned out their use fully

Answer (score 1):

The second one is clearly better. Imagine you call `GetPricesForProduct` a second time with a different id before you have copied all fields. To me the first version is an anti-pattern. Never do that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why is PriceCalculator is a class on its own. The calculated price value is a property that logically belongs to ProductPrice class. The price calculation is not a utility or helper it is tightly dependent on the  ProductPrice and (should) be encapsulated in that class. Accordingly, PriceCalculator should be CaculateProductPrice() method inside ProductPrice class (or Product class). Another reason for that is you don't ever want to instantiate ProductPrice and PriceCalculator separately. In fact, you probably never need to create an object from PriceCalculator on its own.

*Edit:* Added the text (or Product class), since I am not fully aware of the properties and assications in and between Product and ProductPrice.

Comment: The product price is not a singular scalar value. It's actually represented by 3 or 4 different values.

Comment: @AndyBursh, thanks for your explanation. So, is the product price calculated from the individual values? If so, then the calculation belongs to the Product Class. I still can't see it on a class of its own.

Comment: Sorry, I worded that wrongly. There are 4 different prices (special and standard prices with and without tax), not one price with 4 values. These prices are calculated using the starting price, a modifier and a tax rate. Does this change your proposal?

Comment: @AndyBursh, thanks for your clarification. I stick by my proposal. PriceCalculator is not a class.

Comment: Agree the extra PriceCalculator only confuses the issue.

Comment: @JamesAnderson, thanks for voicing your opinion. Most of the other answers surprised me.

Answer (score 1):

Second Method (for all the reasons already given), and:

- make PriceCalculator an interface; one day, you might need one for consumers, one for business customers, one for government customers, one for international customers (EU), one for international customers (outside the EU) etc., so you will implement different Calculators and use the one you need
- make the fields in ProductPrice immutable; maybe it's best to make ProductPrice an interface with some getters (read-only attributes in C#); because you might want to reuse those objects, i.e. by caching them or even using a product price for more than one product (yes, the red mouse costs exactly as much as the green mouse, the yellow mouse and the blue mouse)

Answer (score 1):

Thinking about how prices work and what may happen in the future I would recommend:-

A single "productPrice" class.

The class should have a one or more getPrice methods

```
public int getPrice(getPrice.Type priceType) {}

public int getPrice(getPrice.Type priceType, int offerCode) {} 

public int getPrice(getPrice.Type priceType, int discount) {}
```

Where 'priceType' is an ennum defining the type of price you want.

In a large real-life situation you may offer different prices depending a vast number of variables:-

- Channel -- eg. Web price, may differ from mail order.
- Special Offers -- customers who attended a trade fair, who visited a particular web site may be givein a offer code which gets them a special price.
- Turnover -- customers who buy  a lot get  a better price.
- New Customers -- introductory offers for new customers.
- Location -- Marketing may be targeting a particular region or city.
- Market Segment -- Marketing may be pushing to increase sales to a specific type of customer.

Answer (score 0):

I'll be a little contrary, and say that the first method is better, IF you make this change:

Your GetPricesForProduct() function should be the CONSTRUCTOR for ProductPrice.

Because a ProductPrice object with no particular product doesn't MEAN anything; it's not properly initialized.